# Dialogflow reply with correct tense?

Tags: dialogflow-es

Can anyone advise me on how to ensure Dialogflow replies with correct tense, what I mean is that a user may ask questions such as:

'Can I pay monthly' or 'Is there a set-up cost'

I have entities for these aspects e.g.

'**No Set-up Fees**'

In my reply, I have a variable e.g.

When using the system there are **$System_Benefits**

The issue is this is literal so I'm getting e.g.

**Q.** is there a **set-up** fee?

**A.** When using the system there are **set-up**

The answer doesn't make sense it is not responding with 'No Set-up Fee'

I can't seem to work out how to control the response in a positive or negative tense

There is **'No'** set-up fee
or
**'Yes'** you can pay monthly

Hope this makes sense, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

If your entity reference value was **No Set-up Fees** and **set-up** was a synonym in the [Dialogflow Entities editing interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n73MM.png), then **No Set-up Fees** would be displayed in the answer.

Comment: Thanks, Jeff that does help with part of my issue.

I still need to figure out how do I switch the tense of the reply or maybe I can't do this? 

Do I need to break my 'features/entities' into different types and set up intents to handle these rather than having just one overall array of 'features/entities' e.g. 2 sets have a set which I respond in negative i.e. we have NO set-up fees and another when I say YES you can switch packages at any time?

Comment: Got it.  I think you should split those up into two sets, the positive attributes your system has and the negatives that your system does not have, or you could have the responses come from fulfilment outside of Dialogflow.